# TS2322: Type 'typeof StatusEnum' is not assignable to type 'StatusEnum'

Tags: typescript

Method:

```
  get statusEnum(): StatusEnum {
      return StatusEnum;
  }
```

Enum:

```
export enum StatusEnum {
   Open = 0,
   Edit = 1
 }
```

error:
TS2322: Type 'typeof StatusEnum' is not assignable to type 'StatusEnum'.

Comment: get statusEnum(): StatusEnum {
      return StatusEnum.Open;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to return the **whole** enum use `typeof` keyword:

```js
function getstatusEnum(): typeof StatusEnum {
    return StatusEnum;
}

export enum StatusEnum {
    Open = 0,
    Edit = 1
}
```

In case you want to return **an element** from enum

```js
function getstatusEnum(): StatusEnum {
    return StatusEnum.Open;
}

export enum StatusEnum {
    Open = 0,
    Edit = 1
}
```